# Are Estonia, Iceland, Hungary and Greece in a similar economical level?

Tags: economy, international, europe, geopolitics

I was wondering whether the Estonian or the Icelandic economies, despite being small, are relatively close to the Hungarian and the Greek economies, or whether they are much smaller

Therefore, are Estonia, Iceland, Hungary and Greece in a similar economical level? Or on the contrary, the Hungarian and Greek economies are much bigger than the Estonian and the Icelandic ones?

Comment: I've put an answer. But I wonder if you couldn't; have found these values yourself in a simple web search.  I used google.

Comment: The question is far too vague; there are many ways of measuring a country's economy, including the total size of the economy or per head (which will indicate individual prosperity), and within that, things like productivity, purchasing power, wealth, salary/income, indebtedness, savings, manufacturing capability, resilience to global recession or credit crunch, etc. It will depend on what you want the figures for.

Comment: @StuartF ... or, more cynically, which outcome one is trying to get evidence to support.

Answer (score 4):

**Estonia** 31.03 billion USD (2020)

**Hungary** 155 billion USD (2020)

**Greece** 189.4 billion USD (2020)

**Iceland** 21.71 billion USD (2020)

The Hungarian and Greek economies are much larger than the Estonian and Icelandic economies.

However the GDP per capita is much higher in Iceland ($ 59,260.89) than in the other three ($23000, 16000, 18000 resp)